# Sending script and file content via STDIN

Tags: bash

I generate (dynamically) a script concatenating the following files:

**testscript1**

```
echo Writing File
cat > /tmp/test_file <<EOF
```

**testcontent**

```
line1
second line
```

**testscript2**

```
EOF
echo File is written
```

And I execute by calling

```
$ cat testscript1 testcontent testscript2 | ssh remote_host bash -s --
```

The effect is that the file `/tmp/test_file` is filled with the desired content.

Is there also a variant thinkable where *binary* files can be supplied in a similar fashion? Instead of cat of course `dd` could be used or other Tools, but the problem I see is 'telling' them that the STDIN now ended (can I send ^D through that stream?)

I am not able to get my head around that problem, but there is likely no comparable solution. However, I might be wrong, so I'd be happy to hear from you.

Regards,

Mazze

Comment: I don't get it, are you generating scripts with `cat testscript1`? How?

Comment: The part in front of the `|` is normally a perl program printing shell commands. The example above is a simplification. The issue I have is that I would like to send binary files with `cat testcontent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I send ^D through that stream

**Yes but you don't want to.**

Control+D, commonly notated ^D, is just a character -- or to be pedantic (as I often am), a codepoint in the usual character code (ASCII or a superset like UTF-8) that we treat as a character. You can send that character/byte by a number of methods, most simply `printf '\004'`, but the receiving system won't treat it as end-of-file; it will instead be stored in the destination file, just like any other data byte, followed by the subsequent data that you meant to be a new command and file etc.

^D only causes end-of-file *when input from a terminal* (more exactly, a 'tty' device) -- and then only in 'cooked' mode (which is why programs like `vi` and `less` can do things very different from ending a file when you type ^D). The form of `ssh` you used doesn't make the input a 'tty' device. `ssh` *can* make the input (and output) a 'tty' (more exactly a subclass of 'tty' called a pseudo-tty or 'pty', but that doesn't matter here) if you add the `-t` option (in some situations you may need to repeat it as `-t -t` or `-tt`). But then if your binary file contains any byte with the value `\004` -- or several other special values -- which is quite possible, then your data will be corrupted and garbage commands executed (sometimes), which definitely won't do what you want and may damage your system.

The traditional approach to what you are trying to do, back in the 1980s and 1990s, was 'shar' (shell archive) and the usual solution to handling binary data was 'uuencode', which converts binary data into only printable characters that could go safely go through a link like this, matched by 'uudecode' which converts it back. See [this surviving example from GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/manual/sharutils.html). uuencode and uudecode themselves were part of a communication protocol ['uucp'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP) used mostly for email and Usenet, which are (all) mostly obsolete and forgotten.

However, nearly all systems today contain a 'base64' program which provides equivalent (though not identical) functionality. Within a single system you can do:

```
 base64 <infile | base64 -d >outfile
```

to get the same effect as `cp infile outfile`. In your case you can do something like:

```
 { echo "base64 -d <<END@ >outfile"; base64 <infile; echo "END@"; otherstuff; } | ssh remote bash
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I have to think about it and try something, and will report back.

Comment: This plainly works -- and I understand it! It's just strings/ASCII now, so that `here`-strings approach works again.
One Question however: This talk about the 1980s and 1990s made me think if this is a valid setup. Is there any reason I should use `uuencode` or `base64` these days?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
cat testscript1 testcontent testscript2 | base64 | ssh <options> "base64 --decode | bash"
```

Don't worry about `^D`, because when your input is exhausted, the next processes of the pipeline will notice that they have reached the end of the input file.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, I don't think that it is clear that "Input is exhausted" as long as there are coming shell commands via STDIN. This will not work.
Moreover, it seems that the use of `base64` here is of no effect as the `bash` interpreting stuff in the end still gets the binary data it cannot process.